# SQL Server : concat two columns with delimiter if both not nulll else return third column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here's a sample table

```
FirstName   LastName   UserName
----------------------------------
Bob         Jones      bjones
null        null       tomroberts
null        Ricardo    rricardo
Robby       null       robroy
George      Glass      gglass
```

I'm looking for a select that'll return

```
Jones, Bob
tomroberts
rricardo
robroy
Glass, George
```

If the first name OR last name are null or empty strings, I want to return the user name. Otherwise I want to return the "lastname, firstname"

Can someone help with the query?

Thanks!

Comment: `IIF(FirstName IS NULL OR LastName IS NULL, UserName, 'LastName, ' +   'FirstName')`

Comment: *"If the first name OR last name are null or empty strings"* @GiorgosBetsos .

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I used your approach, just added the empty check along with it. I liked the single line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to using a CASE statement is to use the COALESCE function which returns the first non-NULL argument.

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(NULLIF(LastName,'') + ',' + NULLIF(FirstName,''), UserName)
FROM 
  MyTable
```

Note:- It's important to use the + to concat the columns as this will return NULL if any column contains null. The CONCAT function will return a value that contains the non-NULL parts.

Comment: I used GiorgosBetsos's way but yours works too. Since he didn't post an answer I'll mark yours as such

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` expression and a couple of `NULLIF`s to do this:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN NULLIF(FirstName,'') IS NULL
              OR NULLIF(LastName,'') IS NULL THEN [UserName]
                                             ELSE CONCAT(LastName, ', ', FirstName)
       END
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

*Alternatively, if you prefer, you could use `ISNULL({Value},'') = ''`. Though I would personally suggest you don't allow someone to have a zero length name in your data; such a value should be stored as `NULL`.*

Comment: In this case I would suggest to apply `TRIM` as well - otherwise "  " would be a valid name... anyways - I guess just concatenating via + should do the trick (without `CASE` and so on).

Comment: @Tyron78 not true. T-SQL ignores trailing spaces for equality comparisons. `SELECT CASE WHEN '' = '               ' THEN 1 END;` returns `1`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a4d0b39cd1160fe2b818254f0d9f472c). So if `Firstname` had the value `'    '` then the expression `NULLIF(Firstname,'')` would return `NULL`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e5e53b0d0bdbd80bcd1d750ef9196c70).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `ISNULL` statement:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  firstname NVARCHAR(50)
 ,lastname NVARCHAR(50)
 ,username NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('Bob', 'Jones', 'bjones')
,(null, null, 'tomroberts')
,(null, 'Ricardo', 'rricardo')
,('Robby', null, 'robroy')
,('George', 'Glass', 'gglass')

SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(TRIM(lastname),'') + ', ' + NULLIF(TRIM(firstname),''), username)
  FROM @t
```

Concatenating a string via + results in `NULL` whenever one of the values is `NULL`.